# Django: get all models of an app (including abstract)

Tags: django, django-models

The method [get_models()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models) does not return abstract model classes.

Is there a way to get all model classes of an app (including abstract models)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can implement our own method that basically walks down in the class hierarchy and "harvests" all models with a given `app_label`:

```
from django.db.models import Model

def get_app_models(app_label):
    result = set()
    generation = {Model}
    while generation:
        generation = {sc for c in generation for sc in c.__subclasses__()}
        result.update([c for c in generation if c._meta.app_label == app_label])
    return list(result)
```

We thus move down from `Model`, and each time calculate the *next* generation of `Model` classes in `generation`. Since the number of generations is finite, we know we will eventually stop.

Concurrently, in every generation, we "*harvest*" the models that belong to a given app, by checking if the `c._meta.app_label` is the same as the given `app_label`.

For a `get_app_models('someapp')`, it returns an list with no specific order containing all the models that belong to `someapp`.